# IOS UIImage select from gallery by name (get the name)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

Simply the idea is the user select image from the photo gallery (done)
then it shows in UIImageView (done)

here is the part i am asking for:
1- when user select photo i need to store it name in sqlite DB.
2- later i want to get the photo in another UIImageView from the photo gallery, selecting it by the stored name.

no problem with the database thing, just the name of the image and how to get it from the gallery by name.

Kindly provide me with a solution or workaround.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use ALAsset library please see this page [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048640/retrieving-a-filename-for-an-alasset

Comment: yea i saw this question but it is not related to my question or i don't understand how i can use it ..

Comment: could you show, how you show your camera roll, then pick the image?

Comment: i am selecting it from photo gallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mahmoud,

I just finished answering another question that could help you. Also if you just need to store the name you don't need to use SQLite. You could use something lightweight like a PLIST. The link will show you how to do just that. Save the image and store it with a name for later use.

[How to save a picture in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994924/how-to-save-a-picture-in-ios/12994949#12994949)

Comment: thanks dana, its not exatly what i needed but it is the only solution , thanks a million :D